# How to add string that includes '=' into stringlist?

Tags: c#, java, delphi

A regular expression is used to parse text that include '=' and put split string into a stringlist like key value pair.

But if value contains '=', it can not use list.add(key3+'='+'number=10');

```
key1 this's done
key2 that costs 10 dollars
key3 number=10 // invalid data, error prompt.
...
```

how to solve?
Thank you.

Edit:

Thank you all for help.

If I have to add a string that includes '=' into key, how can I solve it?

for example, the text to be parsed may be like this:

```
maleConsumer=john 1
maleConsumer=eric 2
femaleConsumer=mary 2
maleConsumer=john 8
...
```

I use regex reg='\b\S+\b' parse text and to put maleconsumer=john into key of stringlist, so that in stringlist, john's record will be:

```
maleConsumer=john 9 // maleconsumer=john is key, 9 is value
```

In such case, how can I do it?

Thank you all for your help again.

Comment: can you rephrase the question? what exactly are you trying to achieve? for ex. do you want to get `key3 10` instead?

Comment: Check your tags - is this a java / c# / delphi question?  Smells like a regex question to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine in Delphi

```
var
    sl: TStringList;
begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    try
        sl.Add('key1=this''s done');
        sl.Add('key2=that costs 10 dollars');
        sl.Add('key3=number=10');
        ShowMessage(sl.Values['key3']); // Displays number=10
    finally
        sl.Free;
    end;
end;
```

This is better and still works

```
var
    sl: TStringList;
begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    try
        sl.Values['key1'] := 'this''s done';
        sl.Values['key2'] := 'that costs 10 dollars';
        sl.Values['key3'] := 'number=10';
        ShowMessage(sl.Values['key3']); // Displays number=10
    finally
        sl.Free;
    end;
end;
```

BTW, you can specify the separator with TStringList.NameValueSeparator

Using NameValueSeparator to allow = in key

```
var
    sl: TStringList;
begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    try
        // Select a separater you are sure will never be used
        sl.NameValueSeparator := '|';

        sl.Values['maleConsumer=john'] := '1';
        sl.Values['maleConsumer=eric'] := '2';
        sl.Values['femaleConsumer=mary'] := '2';
        sl.Values['maleConsumer=john'] := '8';

        ShowMessage(sl.Values['maleConsumer=john']); // Displays 8
    finally
        sl.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Mikael for your answer. If I change format of input like my edition above, how can i solve the problem? Thank you again.

Comment: Added sample with NameValueSeparater to allow = in key

Comment: Shame on me... So TStringList *can* work with different delimiters after all. My ignorance couldn't have shown off better. I stand corrected and my so called 'answer', deleted.

Comment: @Garry - Since delphi now supports unicode you should be able to find a character that is extremely unlikely to be a part of the key.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the value contains '=':

```
if(value.indexOf('=') != -1){
 //error prompt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java:

you can use: String.contains() method.

Answer (score 1):

For Delphi; you can set Delimiter and QuoteChar for your strings.
Example:

```
  cars := TStringList.Create;
  // Now add some cars to our list - using the DelimitedText property
  // with overriden control variables
  cars.Delimiter := ' ';        // Each list item will be blank separated
  cars.QuoteChar := '|';        // And each item will be quoted with |'s
  cars.DelimitedText := '|Honda Jazz| |Ford Mondeo| |Jaguar "E-type"|';
```

look [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList) for detail.

Comment: Thank you SimaWB, Please look at my above edition, can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Delphi:

```
var
  LStringList: TStringList;
  LStrValue: string;
begin
  LStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // set the value of a key
    LStringList.Values['a key'] := 'a value';
    // get the value of a key
    LStrValue := LStringList.Values['a key'];
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LStringList);
  end;// trye
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Dorin, Please look at my above edition, can I solve that again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Delphi 2009 or later, use TDictionary instead of TStringList. That way you avoid all these hacks required to get TStringList to work properly.